# DELETE FROM statement not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been trying to get my delete statement working.

This is how it should work: Whenever I press the delete button 'commentDelete' it should delete the comment, that has the commentID equal to the poster.

But instead, it only deletes the most previous comment, posted by the poster. I'm really confused, and can't figure out why. 
Here's my code I tried:

```
function commentsDelete($conn) {
  if(isset($_POST['commentsDelete'])){
    $commentID = $_POST['commentID'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE commentID='$commentID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: commentpage.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you use the wrong ID. The statement is fine

Comment: I echo'd out the comment id, they all seem to work correctly.
For example : commentID1-5, and if i would make a new comment (6), i can only delete the 6th comment.

Comment: What is the type of the `commentID` column?  Is it varchar or numeric?  By the way, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: The commentID is a integer. 
I'm getting started with php, so i'm not super-known with everything, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

> The commentID is a integer

If the `commentID` column is numeric, then you should not be comparing against a quoted text string.  Use this instead:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE commentID=$commentID";
```

Comment: Changed it to : 

    function commentsDelete($conn) {
if(isset($_POST['commentsDelete'])){
    $commentID = $_POST['commentID'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE commentID=$commentID";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: commentpage.php");
} 

Still does not work for me, double checked the commentID , it's a INT with AUTO_INCREMENT on.

Comment: Are you certain that you have any matching data to actually be deleted?

Comment: I managed to fix it, i switched the button names, from my 'delete' and 'edit'  around.. Beginner mistake i guess haha! 


Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from commentId if it is of numeric type in your  **database**